# Getting actual executin time/duration of MDX query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, mdx, sql-server-profiler, ssas-2008

How can I get the actual execution time or actual duration taken by an MDX query to run? I am not interested for compiling, parsing, rendering results etc. I am only interested for the execution time.

In sql profiler, I get two columns one is duration and another one is CPU time. More over it shows in both two rows. One for "query subcube" and one for "query end" event class.
Can you please explain how can I get the desired run time?

Answer (score 2):

I use [MDX Studio](http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio/).  It was originally written by Mosha Pasumansky who was one of the original and main developers of AS.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed the software. I got the following result in the performance section: Time : 100 ms. But do you think the duration is only the running time of the query? or Does it include compiling time, result rendering time? The time belongs to cpu time or duration of SQL profiler? Do you know any similar tool for SQL? Because I have to compare the execution time of an SQL and an MDX that retrieve same records.